# Display a String in any app which have current cursor without using Content provider

Tags: java, android

i'm developping a mobile app, and i want to display a string in any app which have current current cursor, have a focus on an EditText.

In previous post, I saw that I could use Clipboard and AccessibilityService to use 
AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat.ACTION_PASTE.
That's what I tried to do, but no results...

Here's my code in MainActivity for ClipBoard:

```
ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager)getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
                    ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("clipboard data ", recup_nom_quai);
                    clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
```

And then code for my class extends AccessibilityService:

```
public class MyAccessibilityService extends AccessibilityService {


@Override
public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent accessibilityEvent) {
    AccessibilityNodeInfo source = accessibilityEvent.getSource();
    int supportedActions = source.getActions();
    boolean isSupported = (supportedActions & AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat.ACTION_PASTE) == AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat.ACTION_PASTE;

    Log.d(TAG, String.format("AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat.ACTION_PASTE %1$s supported", isSupported ? "is" : "is NOT"));

    if (source != null) {
        ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
        ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("label", "TEST DATA");
        clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
        source.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_PASTE);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Pasted Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    }
}

@Override
public void onInterrupt() {

}
```

So in this class I made a test to display a simple String: "Test Data" but nothing is paste, even in the curent app...

So if this "test" work, I want to display variable: recup_nom_quai from the MainActivity

Here's my code of my config.xml file :

```
<accessibility-service xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:accessibilityFlags="flagDefault"
android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeViewClicked|typeViewFocused"
android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackGeneric"
android:notificationTimeout="0"
android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true"
android:description="@string/config" />
```

and the code of Manifest:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <service android:name=".MyAccessibilityService"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.accessibilityservice"
            android:resource="@xml/config" />
    </service>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

How to do this? Thank's in advance!!

PS: I'm french, my sentences are not correct :p